# SQL Select latest row where value matches

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to return the row from my database, with the highest UID, where the URL column matches http://urltocheck.com.

I've tried all manner of things I can think of, and this is the closest I can get, but I'm getting an SQL syntax error.

My Table is called Adam, and I have the columns... UID (unique), URL (plus loads more). I'm trying to access the MySQL databse via PHP.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Adam`
    WHERE URL='http://urltocheck.com'
    ORDER BY `UID` ASC;
    LIMIT 1;";
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Why is there a semi-colon next to ASC?

Comment: Don't think you need 2 semicolons in your SQL query

Comment: ChrisWillard is right, just remove that semicolon next to ASC and it will work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoul use order DESC and remove the ";" after ASC

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Adam`
WHERE URL='http://urltocheck.com'
ORDER BY `UID` DESC
LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. Can't believe I missed the rampant semicolon!

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I chose this answer as i was the closest to my original code.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. Also, remove `;` at this line `ORDER BY UID ASC;` (didn't noticed that earlier) because of which `limit 1` not coming to picture.

```
SELECT * FROM `Adam`
    WHERE URL='http://urltocheck.com'
    and `UID` = (select max(`uid`) from `Adam`)
```

Answer (score 0):

> with the highest UID

You should order by UID **desc** and limit to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can also ORDER BY MAX ID.

```
<?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM `Adam`
    WHERE URL='http://urltocheck.com'
    ORDER BY MAX(`UID`) DESC;";
```

This is executed faster.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Adam`
        WHERE URL='http://urltocheck.com'
        ORDER BY MAX(`UID`);";

?>
```